# Custom Admin Site in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have problem to change title_header, site_header, index_title in custom admin site.

My admin.py:

```
from reviews.models import Movie, MovieCasts, Review, Actor


class CritiflixAdminSite(AdminSite):
    title_header = 'Aplikacja administracyjna Critiflix'
    site_header = 'Aplikacja administracyjna Critiflix'
    index_title = 'Administracja witryną Critiflix'


movie_admin_site = CritiflixAdminSite(name='critiflix')

movie_admin_site.register(Movie)
movie_admin_site.register(MovieCasts)
movie_admin_site.register(Review)
movie_admin_site.register(Actor)
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', movie_admin_site.urls),

    path('movies/', views.movie_list, name = 'movie_list'),

   path('movies/<int:pk>', views.movie_detail, name = 'movie_detail'),

   path('', views.base, name = 'base')
   ]
```

When i run manage.py nothing is change and models aren't on panel.

Comment: in `admin.py` file did you import `from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite` ?

Comment: do you want to see the model fields in the admin panel or something else?

Comment: I would like to see model fields and changing  title header etc. Whwn i run website i didnt see these elements. But when i use Standard admin.site.register i See every model field in panel admin

Comment: @MohammadGolamDostogir yes sir. Sorry, i didnt copy first line:
admin.py:
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

urls.py:
from reviews.admin import movie_admin_site